# Error - GeneratorFunctionPrototype

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs, koa, koa2

Why am I getting this error in console?

```
GeneratorFunctionPrototype { _invoke: [Function: invoke] }
```

When I'm making a post request I'm getting this error on my console. Though the code is working. Here is my code

```
const authLocal = async (ctx) => {
  const {
    username,
    password,
    email,
    signup
  } = ctx.request.body;
  auth = await authCrud.single({
    $or: [{
      username
    }, {
      email: username
    }]
  });
  if (signup && !auth) {
    try {
      auth = await authCrud.create({
        username,
        password,
        email
      });
    } catch (e) {
      ctx.throw(422, e.message);
    }
  } else if (signup && auth) {
    ctx.throw(409, { message: 'Email or username already registered!!' });
  } else if (!auth) {
    ctx.throw(401, { message: 'No user found' });
  } else if (auth && !compareSync(password, auth.password)) {
    ctx.throw(401, { message: 'Password given is wrong' });
  }
  ctx.session._token = auth._id;
  ctx.body = {
    data: {
      uid: auth._id
    },
    message: 'User registered successfully'
  };
};
```

Also why am I not able to add session or cookie? Please help

Comment: Is that all it reported? That barely looks like an error. And please pick one question/problem per thread; the last line is for a different one.

Comment: Yes, that is all it reported. Now that I've added finally to the try catch, it's gone.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I just found out the cause. I was trying to console the ctx.session. Which was causing the report. Don't know why but it did.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the output you describe can be reproduced using the code you provide. Logging `ctx.session` should just get you the session object.

The reason you're not able to set that session value is that, oddly, koa-session [explicitly disallows session values with leading underscores](https://github.com/koajs/session/blob/622a2d803ff0d42ff1620e3c576b089b3725a65f/lib/session.js#L40). I'm not sure why, but there was [an issue](https://github.com/koajs/session/issues/29) for it back in 2014. Remove the underscore and you're fine.